# Runtime Exception On Springboot upgrade from 2.7.14 to 3.2.0

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator, java-17, aspect

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpointGroupsBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:277)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:792)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:600)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:753)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:455)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:323)
    at com.fsvps.prepaidapi.PrePaidAPIApplication.main(PrePaidAPIApplication.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:563)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:523)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer$AmbiguousBindingException: Still 2 unbound args at this()/target()/args() binding stage, with no way to determine between them
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.maybeBindThisOrTargetOrArgsFromPointcutExpression(AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.java:488)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(AspectJAdviceParameterNameDiscoverer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.core.PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.getParameterNames(PrioritizedParameterNameDiscoverer.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.bindArgumentsByName(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:434)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.calculateArgumentBindings(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:389)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvice(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.instantiateAdvice(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.<init>(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:116)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:144)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I have updated all the dependency version compatible with SpringBoot 3.2.0

**POM.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  

  <groupId>com.fire.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>FireAPI</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springboot.version>3.2.0</springboot.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.14.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
      <version>${springboot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
      <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.9.2</version>
      <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>11.2.3.jre17</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- START PPDCLV-1383-Fixing_ISS_Concern_on_Southbound_Security_Exception_for_API_proxy_151 -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/jacoco-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
      <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.2</version>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>xerces</groupId>
              <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.4</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
        <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                  <version>3.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                    <version>1.9.4</version>
                </dependency>
               </dependencies>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <!-- attached to Maven test phase -->
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>attach-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <locales>en</locales>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>17</source>
          <target>17</target>
          <encoding>Cp1252</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Comment: Add our pom or build file as well. You state you have upgraded all of them but did you really.

Comment: Have you compiled all your code with `-parameters`?

Comment: What does -parameters mean??

Comment: I have the same problem upgrading from 3.1.0 to 3.2.1
Try upgrading to 3.1.0 to see if we can isolate it to 3.1.0-3.2.1

Comment: I had @Scope("prototype") on some jobs removed it and it works. But now the job does not work as intended

Comment: @M.Deinum. Please see the pom.xml. I posted it.

Comment: I would start by cleaning out yuour pom. You have way to much dependencies in there as well as plugins that are managed in newer (compatible) versions of Spring Boot (like remove the `maven-compiler-plugin` at least). Why no `spring-boot-starter-parent` for proper dependency management?

Comment: As @AndyWilkinson and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2-Release-Notes#upgrading-from-spring-boot-31 mentioned, compile with parameter names. Maybe this is not all you need, but it is a start.

Comment: @DeepakPanchal have you tried to upgrade in smaller steps (to 3.0.13, 3.1.7)? That may help to identify your problems more easily. For each step also look for deprecated config warnings on startup.

Comment: I'm not going to solve your problem for you (unless you are paying me to do so). As I stated you are managing too much and work around Spring Boot instead of embracing it, fix your pom.